# Safecracker Registration: Label, Field, Error for Member fields?

Tags: safecracker, safecracker-registration, member-details

Is there a way to access the label, field value, and error of Member fields in a Safecracker form? I'm looking for something like http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/#field-my-field-name, but for member fields. Thoughts?

Comment: Hey man, I will get back with your other email. This week has been crazy busy and got a flood of email, so I am still getting caught up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safecracker only supports channel fields. You'll want to use something like FreeMember, Solspace User, or Zoo Visitor to update member data. (there are a few other addons that also do this, try searching devot-ee for them)

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/user

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor

Comment: Just FYI, he's using my add-on Safecracker Registration. It's similar to Visitor and Profile:edit, but has different features. It's very simple and quite configurable, but a "lite" offering compared to the other 2. https://objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't know he was using Safecracker Registration. Looks like he's in good hands now :) Cheers Justin!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Zoo Visitor as it's set up is the easiest i've seen and the support is very good. I've used it on at least 10 projects and it's up to par.

Comment: I'm using Safecracker Registration. Do you know if I can still do it? Or do I need to migrate to Zoo Visitor?

Comment: Safecracker is a bit limited. You'd have to do a lot to make it bend your way. I think you'll save yourself a lot of headaches if you go with one of the more robust addons for this.